# Shiny dashboard login with renderUI

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am having a problem with this code

```
 output$body <- renderUI({

if(USER$Logged==TRUE)
{uiOutput("test_UI")}

if (USER$Logged == FALSE) {
box(title = "Login",textInput("userName", "Username"),
    passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
    br(),
    actionButton("Login", "Log in"))
 }})
  output$test_UI <- renderUI ({

 tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "me","Hello"),
  tabItem(tabName = "Req", uiOutput("emp1")),
  tabItem(tabName = "Cand", uiOutput("emp2")),
  tabItem(tabName = "Candcomp",uiOutput("emp3")))
 })
```

if I remove both the if conditions in body renderUI it works fine:

```
      output$body <- renderUI({


uiOutput("test_UI")

  }})
    output$test_UI <- renderUI ({

 tabItems(
  tabItem(tabName = "me","Hello"),
  tabItem(tabName = "Req", uiOutput("emp1")),
  tabItem(tabName = "Cand", uiOutput("emp2")),
  tabItem(tabName = "Candcomp",uiOutput("emp3")))
 })
```

Why does this happen pls clarify!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried using a `conditionalPanel` ?

Comment: No. But if you know how to make it work here itself it will be of great help!

Comment: Thanks for the help Michael Bird! Turns out conditional Panel helped me figure out my if else problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
 output$body <- renderUI({

if(USER$Logged==TRUE)
{uiOutput("test_UI")}

else {
box(title = "Login",textInput("userName", "Username"),
passwordInput("passwd", "Password"),
br(),
actionButton("Login", "Log in"))
}})
output$test_UI <- renderUI ({

 tabItems(
 tabItem(tabName = "me","Hello"),
 tabItem(tabName = "Req", uiOutput("emp1")),
 tabItem(tabName = "Cand", uiOutput("emp2")),
 tabItem(tabName = "Candcomp",uiOutput("emp3")))
  }  )
```

It works fine with if and else simply.